# Reading different types of variables from a file in C++

Tags: c++, comments, text-files

I have a problem with my code in C++ and need some help. There are some related questions but I couldn't really understand the answers.
I have a text file ('parameters.dat' in the example below) that I want to read in with my code written in C++. The file includes different types of variables: Boolean, doubles and integers as well as some comments which I want to skip when reading.
My file looks something like that:

```
150    // this is an integer    
4e-1   // this is a double    
1.05   // another double   
0      // this is a logical (Boolean) variable: 0 is false and 1 is true
```

A simple version of the code that I use is

```
int N;
double var_1, var_2;
bool inital;

ifstream read_parameters;
read_parameters.open("parameters.dat");
read_parameters >> N >> var_1 >> var_2 >> initial;
read_parameters.close();
```

The comments seem to ruin everything and even without them there seem to be some problems with reading the logical variables correctly. The file that I try to read is made by me, so I can substitute the '//' above with something else if necessary. Does anyone have any advice?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Read every line in as a string and then parse the string.

Comment: _"The comments seem to ruin everything ..."_ C++ comments are not ignored when reading files with C++. Just remove them from the input file, or skip them with `std::getline()` after reading in each of your variables.

Comment: `ifstream` has no knowledge of C++ syntax. There is no reason it should treat `//` in any special way.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, cheesy way:

Read a token then `read_parameters.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n')` to discard the rest of the line. eg:

```
read_parameters >> N;
read_parameters.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
read_parameters >> var_1;
read_parameters.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
...
```

This doesn't care if a comment exists or not, but requires modification if you have two or more tokens on a line.

Oh, and remember to test the state of the stream after reading. Plugging in "fubar" for one of the doubles will currently ruin things. `read_parameters` will be in an error state that needs to be cleared before you can read it again.

```
if (!read_parameters >> N)
{
    std::cerr << "bad input for parameter N" << std::endl;
    read_parameters.clear();
}
read_parameters.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

Is better, but you probably want to handle an error with something better than a printline.

Answer (score 0):

Take input in a Dynamic Character array then run a for loop in which if a character has ascii 65 - 97 - onward then it will be Alphabet and else if ascii represents integers like 1,2,3 then separte them in another array after calculating total integers as count++ .